trying exemple of EnsembleClustering project
I am trying the exemple of Ensembleclustering project this is the links: https://pypi.org/project/ensembleclustering/
and the example didn't work.
this is the exemple
Installation:
pip install ensembleclustering


>> > import numpy as np

>> > import ensembleclustering as CE

>> > label1 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])

>> > label2 = np.array([2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1])

>> > label3 = np.array([4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])

>> > label4 = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, np.nan])  # `np.nan`: missing value

>> > labels = np.array([label1, label2, label3, label4])

>> > label_ce = CE.cluster_ensembles(labels)

I got error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-869280204161> in <cell line: 11>()
      9 
     10 labels = np.array([labels1, labels2, labels3, labels4])
---> 11 label_ce = CE.cluster_ensembles(labels)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ensembleclustering/ClusterEnsembles.py in to_pymetis_format(adj_mat)
     66         val = row[idx_row, idx_col]
     67         adjncy += list(idx_col)
---> 68         eweights += list(val.toarray()[0])
     69         xadj.append(len(adjncy))
     70 

AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'toarray'

